# Choose algorithm that will search javascript source code and ignore whitespaces

Tags: javascript, c++, algorithm, search

The search itself will be working on the C++. The general idea is to find a string of code that will ignore whitespaces. For example we have such code:

```
function test(){
    let test = 3;
}
```

And all these search patterns will succeed during search in the code above:

1. "test       = 3", "test=3", "test= 3"
2. "function      test()", "function test ( )"

The performance is the main that I need here.
Please advice algorithm that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions with `\s*` or `\s+` (depending on whether at least one space is needed to separate the token) between each token:

1. `\btest\s*\s*3\b`
2. `\bfunction\s+test\s*\(\s*\)`

Comment: I can't use regular expressions in my case due to performance reasons. The search will be on files up to 15 Mb. And it needs to memory similar search cases.

Comment: Then write code that removes any redundant whitespace. But you need to distinguish unnecessary whitespace like around `=` and necessary whitespace after `function`.

Comment: Regular expression performance is generally pretty good, have you actually tested it and found it too slow?